# Optionally running a derived table. Faster to exclude data with the 'where clause' or the 'join condition'

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I want to have a parameter optionally excluding pricing information in a query. I've designed it to exclude information by shortcutting an evaluation to false. Which of these two would be faster and why?

```
DECLARE @fetchPricingData = 'No'
```

**Example 1**, shortcut to false in **Join Condition**:

```
SELECT...
FROM myTable
  FULL JOIN (...) AS derivedPricingTable
     ON derivedPricingTable.key = myTable.key
        AND @fetchPricingData = 'Yes'
```

**Example 2**, shortcut to false in the **Where Clause**:

```
SELECT...
FROM myTable
  FULL JOIN (
     SELECT ...
     FROM pricing_info
     WHERE @fetchPricingData = 'Yes'
  ) AS derivedPricingTable
     ON derivedPricingTable.key = myTable.key
```

Comment: Inspect the execution plan and find out. Performance is totally database specific... the query is just a logical expression of the results you want. How that is carried out under the hood depends on many many factors.

Comment: Filtering for a `full join` is quite tricky.  The two are not equivalent.

Comment: Your query is malformed. The predicate `derivedPricingTable.key = myTable.key` silently changes the `FULL JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`. I would suggest you fix the join first and then you can tackle the performance.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Voting to close.

Comment: @GordonLinoff's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809767/sql-server-derived-table-data-storage), helped.

Comment: @TheImpaler, must be something about the way I've described it here. Works fine in my query. Feel free to close this or I can delete it.

Comment: The query runs, yes, but it's not doing what you think it's doing. Please read my first comment and fix the logic of the query.